# Trouble order by when using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables: `books`, `users` (Many to many relationship).

User will follow books and save data in pivot table: `follows` (`id`, `user_id`, `manga_id`).

How can I count total of follows for each book and order by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins will be best in terms of performance, so this is what you should do:

```
Book::join('follows', 'follows.manga_id', '=', 'books.id')
 ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'follows.user_id')
 ->selectRaw('books.*, count(users.id) as follows_count')
 ->groupBy('books.id')
 ->orderBy('follows_count')
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have set up your models and relations...

```
$books = Book::with('users')->get()
             ->sortByDesc(function($model){
                 return $model->users->count();
             });
```

(`users` here is the name of the relationship, replace it if you have a different name)

Answer (score 0):

With following code you can get followers of each book via an array

```
$books=DB::table('books')->get();
$total_follows=array('');
 foreach($books as $book)
   $total_follows[$book->id]=DB::table('pivot')->where('manga_id',$book->id)->count();
```

echo $total_follows[$the_book_id_you_need];